# Django - Slow Ajax response seems to be delayed

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I am using a jquery Ajax call to retrieve some json data from the server. I used the module time to calculate the time it takes to create the json data and it is done a lot before than the success function is launched on the client side.

On the server side the json is created in 0.9 sec but the success function is called after 30 sec or more.

What could be happening?

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/basqui/layer/shapefile/attributesTable/loader/{{ layer.pk }}/",
      success: function(data) {
                  alert('data received');

                },
});
```

Server side function:

```
def attributeTableLoader(request, shapefile_id):
    start_time = time.time()
    features_selected = Feature.objects.filter(shapefile__pk=shapefile_id).order_by("id_relat")

    data = [dict(feature.attribute_value, **{"id":str(feature.id_relat)}) for feature in features_selected]
    jsonData= json.dumps(data)
    print("Temps final: --- %s seconds ---" % str(time.time() - start_time))
    return StreamingHttpResponse(jsonData, content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: Is it a lot of data? It may simply take that long to get downloaded by the browser. Check the Network Tool in your DevTools to see the request progress/size on the browser-side. :)

Comment: ok its 700KB, could it be the reason?

Comment: in the Network tool I see: 1 sec waiting and 22 sec for reception

Comment: Nah, that's not actually that bad size-wise. Hmm... 22 seconds is awfully long. I assume you're testing with the Django runserver?

Comment: yes, so you think thats the source of the slowliness?

Comment: No; it shouldn't be that slow. Are you testing on your localhost or with an actual server over the internet? Also, question: why are you using a `StreamingHttpResponse` instead of a regular `HttpRespone` (or even a `JsonResponse`)?

Comment: That's right! it tooks 2secs with HttpResponse. I thought both were similar but apparently not

Comment: Interesting. Shall I post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Django's [`StreamingHttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects) can be much slower than a traditional [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse)** for small responses.

Try to shy away from using it if you don't need to; the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/) actually recommend that "`StreamingHttpResponse`should only be used in situations where it is absolutely required that the whole content isn’t iterated before transferring the data to the client."